# Testing strategy. PHPUnit mocks within zend framework controller integration/smoke tests

Tags: zend-framework, tdd, phpunit, integration-testing

I have a complex backend application, using zf 1.11.11 and phpunit 3.5.15. The application has some complex communication components (soap, rest, etc.). In the CIS or dev testing environment I have to mock this models, because I can't established a connection or a request to the productive 3rd party backends. So with mocking the unittest layer works really good. Full coverage - no problem. The problem is that I can't use this technique during the controller integration tests. Its a higher layer which complete hide the models. So I guess it's impossible to inject mocks at this point. On the one hand this is right and good because it's the nature of integration tests, on the other hand I get a very low coverage on the controller tests.

Summary of the problem:

- I can't create test services that communicate to the commponents (high costs)
- I can't inject component mocks during controller testing (I only set request data and trigger the dispatcher)
- My coverage on controller is way to low

I've seen a solution which implements all as a plugin. So that some namespace redirecting can point to the mock plugins. But i don't think that this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your dependency injection issues on your testable classes, add the following functions, or injection into the constructor.

```
function setDependentProperty(Type $value)
{
    $this->_dependency = $value;
    return $this;
}

function getDependentProperty()
{
    if (!isset($this->_dependency)) {
       $this->_dependency = new DependencyType();
    }
    return $this->_dependency;
}
```

Then use Mocks in the tests

```
function testUseMockedService()
{
    $testedItem = new ObjectToTest();
    $mock = $this->getMock('Service_ToMock',
        array('functionToMock')
    );
    $mock->expects($this->exactly(1))
        ->method('functionToMock')
        ->will($this->returnValue($valueYouWant));

    $testedItem->setDependency($mock);
    $returnValue = $testedItem->doStuff();

    $this->assertEquals($something, $returnValue);
}
```

Understand that Unittests are not integration tests, should be very isolated

```
http://www.typemock.com/unit-tests-integration-tests
```

Understand that there is no "Right" amount of coverage

> http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=204677

Comment: Yes I know exactly the difference between unittest and integration testing. I never set them to the same level in the question. The phpunit/zf1 controller tests (http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.test.phpunit.html) does not give you a "direct" access to the controller. This is intended! And good! You only trigger the dispatcher. You have no access to lower components. Only to the request and the respond.

Comment: You should be pushing your logic into the model, there should be almost nothing to test in the controllers. eg, all dependencies and services should be accessed via models. Use the first section I talked about above to inject your dependencies into the models. As an example, we dont even test our controllers on my project...